# Java Client/Server Programming -- BufferedReader for Reading Data from Android Device will not Function on Client Side, but will on Server Side

Tags: android, sockets, bufferedreader, readline

I am writing an example Java Server/Android Client pair of programs in order to learn how to use sockets on the Android.  It is a simple set of programs; the client sends a string of text to the server, and the server echoes it back to the client.  The server is using straight-run Java, and the client is an Android Smartphone using the Jelly Bean version of the system.  Although I can get the Android device to function as a server, I have had a very difficult time getting it to work as a client.

My server code is as follows:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class TCPIPServer3
{
    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception 
    { 
        // Declaration Section:
        // Declare a server socket and a client socket for the server
        // Declare an input and an output stream
        ServerSocket echoServer = null;
        String line;
        DataInputStream is;
        BufferedReader br;
        PrintStream os;
        Socket clientSocket = null;

        // Try to open a server socket on port 9999
        // Note that we can't choose a port less than 1023 if we are not
        // privileged users (root)
        try {
            echoServer = new ServerSocket(9999);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        // Create a socket object from the ServerSocket to listen and accept
        // connections.
        // Open input and output streams
        try {
            clientSocket = echoServer.accept();
            is = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            // As long as we receive data, echo that data back to the client.
            while (true)
            {
                line = br.readLine();
                System.out.println(line);
                os.println(line);
                os.flush();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

My client code is as follows:

```
package com.example.androidtcpclient3;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ClientActivity extends Activity {

       private Button bt;
       private TextView tv;
       private Socket socket;
       private String serverIpAddress = "10.0.2.2";
       //private String serverIpAddress = "10.1.200.100";
       private static final int REDIRECTED_SERVERPORT = 9999;

       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.client);
          bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
          tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
          Thread cThread = new Thread(new ClientThread());
          cThread.start();
       }

       public class ClientThread implements Runnable {
           public void run() {
              try {
                     InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
                     socket = new Socket(serverAddr, REDIRECTED_SERVERPORT);
                  } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                     e1.printStackTrace();
                  } catch (IOException e1) {
                     e1.printStackTrace();
                  }
              bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(View v) {
                     try {
                        String line;

                        DataInputStream is;
                        BufferedReader br;
                        PrintWriter out;         

                        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
                        String str = et.getText().toString();
                        out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),true);
                        out.println(str);
                        Log.d("Client", "Client sent message");

                        is = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                        line = br.readLine();                       
                        tv.setText(line);
                     } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        tv.setText("Error1");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                     } catch (IOException e) {
                        tv.setText("Error2");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                     } catch (Exception e) {
                        tv.setText("Error3");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                     }
                  }
               });
           }
       }
}
```

I cannot get the program to execute past the statement "line = br.readLine();" on the Android client.  For some reason, this statement always throws an exception every time it is reached in the code.  In the client program's execution, this results in the string "Error3" being written to the client's TextView widget.  However, I have been able to confirm that the server can *read* data from the client successfully.  The readLine() method seems to be showing asymmetrical behavior between clients and servers.

Any help in resolving this issue would be appreciated.

UPDATE: My stack trace is as follows:

```
07-18 13:56:36.802: W/System.err(2164): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
07-18 13:56:36.832: W/System.err(2164):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
07-18 13:56:36.842: W/System.err(2164):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:163)
07-18 13:56:36.842: W/System.err(2164):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:513)
07-18 13:56:36.852: W/System.err(2164):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:488)
07-18 13:56:36.862: W/System.err(2164):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
07-18 13:56:36.872: W/System.err(2164):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
07-18 13:56:36.882: W/System.err(2164):     at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:84)
07-18 13:56:36.882: W/System.err(2164):     at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:244)
07-18 13:56:36.894: W/System.err(2164):     at java.io.BufferedReader.fillBuf(BufferedReader.java:130)
07-18 13:56:36.902: W/System.err(2164):     at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:354)
07-18 13:56:36.902: W/System.err(2164):     at com.example.androidtcpclient3.ClientActivity$ClientThread$1.onClick(ClientActivity.java:75)
07-18 13:56:36.912: W/System.err(2164):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
07-18 13:56:36.922: W/System.err(2164):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
07-18 13:56:36.932: W/System.err(2164):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-18 13:56:36.932: W/System.err(2164):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-18 13:56:36.942: W/System.err(2164):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-18 13:56:36.952: W/System.err(2164):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-18 13:56:36.952: W/System.err(2164):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-18 13:56:36.962: W/System.err(2164):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-18 13:56:36.972: W/System.err(2164):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-18 13:56:36.972: W/System.err(2164):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-18 13:56:36.983: W/System.err(2164):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: you are updating ui inside run method of thread. post stack trace

Comment: I didn't know that that could be an issue.  I am still pretty new to Android programming.  With that being said, how do you post a stack trace?

Comment: OK, I figured out how to post the stack trace.  I just wasn't familiar with the term yet.  I put the stack trace in the edited question area above.

Comment: networkonmainthreadexception my first comment holds good

Comment: I do not see how the statement that the program crashes on, that is, line = br.readLine(), updates the ui.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html. now you can make out whats wrong and why.